# Program Status Dashboard for End-Users

Tags: automation, dashboard, tracking

We have several small scripts running on a regular basis. For example, say we have 2 scripts to pull order information from 2 different websites (SiteA, SiteB). These scripts can be in a variety of languages (Java, PHP, C++, etc..).

While I can just go to a log file and see information such as number of orders imported, last run time, error messages, etc, this isn't something a normal end-user would like to see.

Is there a way to display this kind of information in an easy-to-use dashboard-like manner?

I was looking into Graylog2 but that is not exactly what I had in mind as it is more about aggregating information over periods of time rather than giving status updates about the last run of a program.

Comment: My first thought was https://jenkins.io/, but then I see "number of orders imported" and I suspect the need for a custom solution, not off the shelf.